# Is there a way to change variable "gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled']=false to "true" in a ruby file through linux command

Tags: linux, shell, variables, sed, fileupdate

I tried various solution on the internet like below Example-

**sed -i -e "/^gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled']=/s|.*|gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled']=true|" testFile.rb**

but nothing seems to work.

**Sample File:** cat testFile.rb

Hello it is me

a = true

gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled']=false

Answer (score 0):

Sed will see the square brackets as part of a regular expression and so these will need to be escaped. The command should therefore be:

```
sed -i -e "/^gitlab_rails\['omniauth_enabled'\]=/s|.*|gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled']=true|" testFile.rb
```